# What does super.onInit() do?

Tags: spfx

```
VideoChatWebPart extends BaseClientSideWebPart

    protected async onInit(): Promise<void> {
    ...
    return super.onInit();

}
```

We have a class that contains the method onInit(). Now, I saw that we did a super.onInit() which probably calls the onInit() method of the parent class from which it extends from, but I have no idea if it's necessary and what the function does exactly. Is this just some boilerplate code we can get rid of or not?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, `super` is the keyword that refers back the parent class.  Any time you are overriding a method from the base class, it is best practice to call the parent implementation.  You never know when the base framework has (or may add in a future version) has necessary code in the base class.
Like nearly every coding standard, there are exceptions when you will need to completely replace the base implementation  -- but in the absence of a specific justifiable reason not to, you should always call the super method of a function you override.

Answer (score 0):

super() will calls the constructor of its parent class. This is required when you need to access some variables from the parent class.

Here is a very nice explanation about super in react.

https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-use-of-super-in-the-ReactJs-application/answer/Divyesh-Padamani?ch=99&share=b00b8e1a&srid=uln2f